# dataframe add hyphen in a column based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column which should have data in below format:

xxxx-xxx

But I see for some records hyphen is missing so I need to update the data for these records. Data I see is following below format:

xxxx-xxx ( for few records)
xxxxxxx ( for remaining records)

For the records which are in xxxxxxx  format, I need to update the data and insert hyphen (-) at 6th position to convert it to expected format (xxxx-xxx).

My logic:
I am trying to filter records which does not have length of 8, and does not contain hyphen (-) and then insert hyphen at sixth place.

Code I tried ( but it is giving errors):

```
if df.col.str.len()!=9 and '-' not in df['col']:
     df['col']=df['col'].str[:5] +'-' + df['col'].str[5:]
```

is there any easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could get it done with several approaches.

```py
# Option1: Using a lambda function
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x[:5] + '-' + x[5:]
     if len(x) != 9 and '-' not in x else x)

# Option2: Using mask
mask = (df['col'].str.len() != 9) & (~df['col'].str.contains('-').fillna(True))
df.loc[mask, 'col'] = df.loc[mask, 'col'].str[:5] + '-' + df.loc[mask, 'col'].str[5:]

# Option3: Using a function to update
def update_format(value):
    if len(value) != 9 and '-' not in value:
        return value[:5] + '-' + value[5:]
    return value

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(update_format)
```

Certainly, additional options are likely available.

Comment: Option 2 is the only one I'd recommend of these options, as it's the only one that's vectorised.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome one of the record has NaN value so it is throwing this error :
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome I tried below (earlier I was trying option 1) :


mask = (df['col'].str.len() != 9) & (~df['col'].str.contains('-'))
df.loc[mask, 'col'] = df.loc[mask, 'col'].str[:5] + '-' + df.loc[mask, 'col'].str[5:]


and it throws below error:

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: If the value was `NaN`, `df['col'].str.contains('-')` would also be `NaN`. `~` cannot be applied to `NaN`, causing the issue. Using `(~df['col'].str.contains('-').fillna(True))` handles NaN values properly.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, this is also interpretable as a regular expression normalization:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': ['ABCDEFG', '1234-567', 'abcdefg', '1234567890'],
})

df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(
    pat=
    r'^(\w+)'     # Some alphanumeric
    r'-?'         # Optional pre-existing hyphen
    r'(\w{3})$',  # 3 alphanumeric suffix
    repl=r'\1-\2',
    regex=True,
)
print(df)
```

```
           col
0     ABCD-EFG
1     1234-567
2     abcd-efg
3  1234567-890
```